# Trigger mutating issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have number of different cars in the table and each car has its own price.
Every time something is gets updated or new row is inserted in table I need to recompute and update average price.

I am trying to use `AVG()` function inside the Trigger but suddenly getting run time error:
`ORA-04091: table abcde.SCL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

I believe that solution is to use statement instead of row trigger trigger. In this case statements triggers do no allow to use `:new.ID or :old.ID`, then how do I detect which car brand is updated, in order to recompute an average?

```
create or replace trigger AvgTrigger
after insert on cars
for each row
declare     
    carAvg number;
begin   
    SELECT Avg(price) into carAvg from car where id# = :new.id#;    
end;
```

Comment: Define a view on cars with `avg(price) over (partition by id#) as carAvg` in the select list. I guess. The trigger you are showing has no data modifications, no output for the average calculation so could be removed entirely.

Comment: trigger is not finished yet, that is a reason.

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936  Basically the problem is that the table is changing while the trigger is running.  This is a complex deal, let's allow Tom Kite to answer your questions for this one.

Comment: Is cars and car different tables or you mistyped? Try compound trigger - see oracle help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this kind of situation is to use a row-level trigger to record some information, like the id# modified, in a temporary table, then use a statement-level trigger to read that information and perform the desired work.

However, in this case I would question whether that is worthwhile at all.  Consider computing the average in your queries when it is needed; or embedding it in a view as suggested in Shannon's comment; or embedding it in materialized view if computing it on the fly is too much overhead.