# Trigger to delete column after update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I made trigger to delete data if inserted or updated row got BLOCKED=0:

```
create  or replace  trigger DATA_SOURCE_delete_blocked
after insert or update
on DATA_SOURCE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.BLOCKED=0)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM DATA_SOURCE WHERE DATA_SOURCE_ID=:NEW.DATA_SOURCE_ID;
end;
```

it works for insert (at least data not writed, but may be with errors), but for update it doesn't work because of mutating error:

```
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Is there any easy ways to delete rows after insert/update w/o creating view's?

UPDATE:
Resolved my problem with compaund trigger:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE  TRIGGER DATA_SOURCE_DELETE_BLOCKED
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON DATA_SOURCE when (new.BLOCKED=0)
COMPOUND TRIGGER
ID1 NUMBER;
AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  ID1:=:NEW.DATA_SOURCE_ID;
END AFTER EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM DATA_SOURCE WHERE DATA_SOURCE_ID=ID1;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END DATA_SOURCE_DELETE_BLOCKED;
```

Comment: Why insert data at all if you want it be deleted immediately? About update see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16367601/2899629).

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin - Agreed.  Also, principle of least surprise here: I'm going to be rather confounded if inserting into a table causes it to `DELETE` rows.  This suggests something strange is going on in your overall design.  Why can't you have your application issue the delete?  Or what about creating a regular sp to perform maintenance to this table?

Comment: I inserting it to make it work both ways from one trigger - for insert and for update. Yes, i could make BEFORE INSERT trigger to break inserting, but I'll need to add another trigger to delete BLOCKED=0 rows.

Comment: I read answer from your link, Yaroslav, but tbh, I don't rly know, what "use a statement-level trigger" actually means. With writing data like ID to temp table is not a problem.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? If you're using 11g, you can solve this using compound triggers. Otherwise, you'll need two triggers- before update row level and after update statement level. I have not tried the other part.

Comment: @Rachcha thx, it works for me. I'll add answer in the topic.